# Beginner problems in Tikz (vertical lines, letters, ...)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm new to Tikz and I'm trying to recreate this picture right here. 
[image: picture I want to recreate]

I've not gotten really far. 
I've been trying to this right here (note that the coordinates of `dashed`are definitely wrong, I didn't know how to set them).

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikz{\draw (0,0) rectangle (7,0.75);}
\tikz{\draw [dashed] (0.5,0) -- (0.5,0.75);}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But it doesn't seem to work no matter how I set the variables of `dashed`. Could someone please show me how to achieve this kind of picture? Also, I can't seem to add writing inside the box, I've tried so much now, that I've completely lost the overlook of what I've tried so far and what not.

Comment: `\tikz{..}` is a shortform for `\begin{tikzpicture} .. \end{tikzpicture}`. Don't put the former inside the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why TikZ?  Just use a `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\mc{\multicolumn{1}}
\begin{tabular}{*7c}
  2 & 1 & \multicolumn{5}{c}{509 bytes} \\
  \hline
  \mc{|c}{CircID} & \mc{|c}{CMD} & \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{DATA} \\
  \hline
  \\ % empty line
  2 & 1 & 2 & 6 & 2 & 1 & 498 \\
  \hline
  \mc{|c}{CircID} & \mc{|c}{Relay} & \mc{|c}{StreamID} & \mc{|c}{Digest} & \mc{|c}{Len} & \mc{|c}{CMD} & \mc{|c|}{DATA} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @AnneKunstmann If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](//tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and marking it as [accepted answer](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).